# "'isDeveloperModeEnabled' is deprecated: This no longer needs to be set during development. " What is isDeveloperModeEnabled used for

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

As a part of upgrading the code base to Swift5, I have updated Firebase pod in my project. After that i started getting warning as below.

> `isDeveloperModeEnabled` is deprecated: This no longer needs to be set during development. Refer to documentation for additional details..

Can somebody explain what is the alternative way to resolve this issue

```
remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()

let conSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)

if TargetBuild.isProd {

   remoteConfig.configSettings = RemoteConfigSettings()

} else if settings.isDeveloperModeEnabled {

    remoteConfig.configSettings = conSettings

} else {
    print("Could not set config settings")
}
```

i need to resolve the warning on above code. This was an existing codebase. When i did a global search, i didnt see this value getting used. somebody please help me

Answer (score 22):

Old way:

```
let remoteConfigSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)
```

New way:

```
let remoteConfigSettings = RemoteConfigSettings()
remoteConfigSettings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
```

The iOS documentation does not yet mention that `developerModeEnabled` is deprecated, but an updated commented example can be found here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/config/ConfigExample/RemoteConfigViewController.swift#L57 ([README here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/config))

Answer (score 1):

That config setting is deprecated.. With a simple google search..

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.html#getMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds()

The docs say to use `getMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds()` instead of `isDeveloperModeEnabled()`.

Update -- Android docs say it is deprecated, iOS does not say anything about deprecating isDeveloperModeEnabled

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/RemoteConfigSettings

Comment: The URL points to Android SDK docs, while the question relates to iOS.

Comment: Woops -- Didn't even realize this. The OP didn't question this though.. Maybe it worked?? Perhaps the iOS docs are outdated as the iOS isDeveloperModeEnabled is not marked as deprecated.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/RemoteConfigSettings

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Objective-C`, you can solve the issue with:

```objectivec
FIRRemoteConfigSettings *remoteConfigSettings = [[FIRRemoteConfigSettings alloc] init];
[remoteConfigSettings setMinimumFetchInterval:0];
```