# Firebase Remote Config isDeveloperModeEnabled() is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to have a remote config parameter using the Remote Config feature of Firebase so I can get values from Firebase and use it in app. I already use it with no problem but after a Firebase update, I get this warning:

[image: screenshot]

I tried to use `getMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds()` instead of `isDeveloperModeEnabled()` in order to avoid the warning.

Here is my code:

```
final FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemopteconfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
long cachExpiration = 0;
if (mFirebaseRemopteconfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
    cachExpiration = 0;
}
mFirebaseRemopteconfig.fetch(cachExpiration)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                final String funct = mFirebaseRemopteconfig.getString("functionn");
                if (getPackageName().compareTo(funct) != 0) {
                    finish();
                }
                mFirebaseRemopteconfig.activateFetched();
            }
        }
    });
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693336/isdevelopermodeenabled-is-deprecated-this-no-longer-needs-to-be-set-during-d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About `setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds`, it is [officially said](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#throttling):

> Keep in mind that this setting should be used for development only,
>   not for an app running in production. If you're just testing your app
>   with a small 10-person development team, you are unlikely to hit the
>   hourly service-side quota limits. But if you pushed your app out to
>   thousands of test users with a very low minimum fetch interval, your
>   app would probably hit this quota.

Although you can `setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds` other than the default value (= 12 hours), it's all up to you about whether it would hit the quota or not, and may lead to `FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchThrottledException`.

Now, the new API requires you to `setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds` for altering the interval. It is a method of **`FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder`**. So you must build a `FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings` object through the builder after `setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds`, and then `setConfigSettingsAsync` the built `FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings` to your `FirebaseRemoteConfig`.

Here is an example of my own implementation:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    cacheExpiration = 0;
} else {
    cacheExpiration = 43200L; // 12 hours same as the default value
}

FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings
        .Builder()
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(cacheExpiration)
        .build();

config = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
config.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
config.fetch(cacheExpiration).addOnCompleteListener(activity, onCompleteListener);
```

--------------------------- revised ---------------------------

For your porpose

> checking if package name is the same

you don't need `isDeveloperModeEnabled()` or any interval settings. Just `fetch()` without any settings (but with default settings):

```
mFirebaseRemopteconfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
mFirebaseRemopteconfig.fetch()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                final String funct = mFirebaseRemopteconfig.getString("functionn");
                if (getPackageName().compareTo(funct) != 0) {
                    finish();
                }
                mFirebaseRemopteconfig.activateFetched();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: please how to bring the value functionn which is in my firebase ? can you write the whole code for me please .that code is cheking if package name is the same that i enter in firebase if not app will crash .i do that to prevent people reverse engering my app

Comment: @saalgu Updated my answer.